# Mapping key and values in JSON

Tags: python, arrays, json, list

I am trying to map key and values to write it in JSON and I am unable to convert it as required in the below template:

`{Pregnancies : [], Glucose : [], BloodPressure : [], SkinThickness : [579], Insulin : [8,13,111,153,...so on]`

Below is the code I am working on currently (`names` is a list having values `Blood Pressure, SkinThickness ...` and `Outlier` records has values `[], [],[579],[8,13,111,153,...]`.

```
Outlier_records
names
joinedlist = names + Outlier_records
joinedlist

json.dumps(joinedlist)
os.chdir(Output)
with open('Outlier_Records.txt', 'w') as json_file:
  json.dump(joinedlist, json_file)
```

The output that I am getting now is attached in the image below whereas I am actually expecting the output to be mapped as above

`{Pregnancies: [], BloodPressure: [], SkinThickness: [579], Insulin: [8,13,111,153,...so on]`

[image]

Comment: How is your data? names is a list of names from Pregnancies to Outcome, right? What about Outlier_records? Is a list of lists? Does it have the same number of elements as names?

Comment: list + list != JSON  json.dumps expects a dict

Answer (score 0):

Instead of joining your lists you can make a dict from them to pass to `json.dumps`:

```
import json

keys = ['apples','bananas','fish']
values = [1,2,[1,2,3]]

out = dict(zip(keys,values))

print(json.dumps(out))
```

outputs:

```
{"apples": 1, "bananas": 2, "fish": [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The template you provided is in json format which are dicts in python, so in this case you would need to create a dictionary and add the corresponding data to it in the form of key-value paris with the code below.

```py
import json

names = ["blood", "test", "test1", "ntek"]
outliner_records = [
    [],
    [],
    [579],
    [8,13,111,153]
]

joinedDict = {}
for i in range(len(names)):
    joinedDict[names[i]] = outliner_records[i]

with open("tt.json", "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(joinedDict, json_file)
```